# (Laravel workers and Supervisor) Working with N number of parallel workers for bulk sending message

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduling, supervisord, worker

I'm developing a laravel service that forwards bulk messages to X number of recipients in parallel. I came to use N parallel workers(with the help of supervisor) for processing the request and bulk sending the messages in a queue, which greatly increased the speed of sending message. What I did was, when a queue gets a recipient, I updated a Boolean status field of that recipient record to block other queues to prevent processing at the same time. *May be this approach was not so great after all*.

Everything was working fine when I tested with few number recipients. But then when I increased the recipients to thousands and so for that I increased the  workers for it. There were cases that same message was sent multiple of times for a same recipient.

I cannot reduce the workers too because of the delay it will cause to forward those messages. Is there any optimal way to send the bulk messages without compromising the performance and also prevent sending the message to the same recipient multiple of times?

Comment: Could you show us how you create the jobs and what the jobs do exactly? To me it feels like you've implemented a custom locking mechanism when instead Laravel provides one for you